# If postgres database size is small enough to fit in memory, how would it compare to an in-memory database?

Tags: postgresql, redis

On a small database size, which can easily fit within the amount of memory available for postgres to use as a cache, how would performance compare to an in-memory database such as Redis?

My use case may benefit from retaining relational modelling, but size constraints mean it could also fit in available memory.

Or is there nothing to be gained from a specific in-memory database in this case as the postgres cache would achieve broadly the same thing for all practical purposes?  Or are there some fundamental differences I am missing (excluding the fact that one is relational and the other isn't, of course).

Answer (score 2):

From Martin Kleppmann's [Designing Data Intensive Applications](https://dataintensive.net/) (p89):

> Counterintuitively, the performance advantage of in-memory databases is not due to the fact that they don’t need to read from disk. Even a disk-based storage engine may never need to read from disk if you have enough memory, because the operating system caches recently used disk blocks in memory anyway. Rather, they can be faster because they can avoid the overheads of encoding in-memory data structures in a form that can be written to disk.